# OpenCV free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, memory-leaks, runtime-error

I am getting the next error while running an application that reads some data from files, extracts the features of an image and predicts a result using a set of pre-trained classifiers:

```
> *** glibc detected *** ./SVMread: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbfeb2670 ***
> ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb5fe8ee2]
> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb61e451f]
> ./SVMread(_ZN2cv17FlannBasedMatcherD0Ev+0x1c)[0x804b214]
> ./SVMread[0x804ca96] ./SVMread[0x804c0e1]
> ./SVMread(_ZN2cv3PtrINS_17DescriptorMatcherEED1Ev+0x11)[0x804b6e9]
> ./SVMread[0x804a8cc]
> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb5f8c4d3]
> ./SVMread[0x8049ef1]
> ======= Memory map: ======== 08048000-08050000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 101213     /home/srt/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/SVMread
> 08050000-08051000 r--p 00007000 00:14 101213    
> /home/srt/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/SVMread 08051000-08052000 rw-p
> 00008000 00:14 101213     /home/srt/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/cpp/SVMread
> ...
```

I am thinking that the conflicting part is in one of the next sections of the code, but I really can't find a solution on the web nor in the OpenCV documentation.

```
     SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor1;
     Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = &extractor1;
     FlannBasedMatcher matcher1;
     Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = &matcher1;

     BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowide(extractor,matcher);
```

or in:

```
CvFileStorage* storage = cvOpenFileStorage( "svm1.yml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );

 const char * c;
 string clase;
 CvFileNode*  cFN;

 for (unsigned int i = 0; i<Vclases.size(); i++) {              
  clase = Vclases[i];
  c = (clase).c_str();                      
  cFN = cvGetFileNodeByName( storage , 0, c );          
  cout << "reading  " << clase  <<  endl;
  classes_classifiers[clase].read(storage, cFN );           

 }
```

Edit: The valgrind output confirms that there is a problem in:

```
CvFileStorage* storage = cvOpenFileStorage( "svm1.yml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
```

Valgrind:

```
> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==23398==    at 0x56585C0: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:1659)
> ==23398==    by 0x5653FAE: strtod (strtod.c:70)
> ==23398==    by 0x41425B1: icv_strtod(CvFileStorage*, char*, char**) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
> ==23398==    by 0x415875F: icvYMLParseValue(CvFileStorage*, char*, CvFileNode*, int, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
> ==23398==    by 0x804A377: main (SVMread.cpp:64)
> ==23398==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
> ==23398==    at 0x56575E4: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:424)
```

I'm a newbie with pointers and memory allocation so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: The problem was that cv:Ptr works with dinamically allocated objects, that's why was happening an error while trying to free the pointers initialised by reference. So, the right declaration of pointers is:

```
 Ptr<DescriptorMatcher > matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher;
 Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor(new SurfDescriptorExtractor());
```

And the segmentation fault is gone.

(Note: I found the solution thanks to the answer made here: [OpenCV/C++ - How to free pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396006/opencv-c-how-to-free-pointers/17396015#17396015)