# OpenCV/C++ - How to free pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, memory-management

I had to do a trick involving cv::Ptr (pointers) in order to be able to call a specific function, but it seems that the program has some problem when tries to free the memory after the program execution because a segmentation fault happens.

---

1.Code:

```
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor1;
 Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = &extractor1;      
 FlannBasedMatcher matcher1;
 Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = &matcher1;
```

2.Errors:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==23559==    at 0x56585C0: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:1659)
==23559==    by 0x5653FAE: strtod (strtod.c:70)
==23559==    by 0x41425B1: icv_strtod(CvFileStorage*, char*, char**) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x415875F: icvYMLParseValue(CvFileStorage*, char*, CvFileNode*, int, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x4158BA4: icvYMLParseValue(CvFileStorage*, char*, CvFileNode*, int, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x41593F7: icvYMLParseValue(CvFileStorage*, char*, CvFileNode*, int, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x41593F7: icvYMLParseValue(CvFileStorage*, char*, CvFileNode*, int, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x4159DE0: cvOpenFileStorage (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x804A377: main (SVMread.cpp:66)
==23559==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==23559==    at 0x56575E4: ____strtod_l_internal (strtod_l.c:424)
==23559== 
==23559== Invalid read of size 4
==23559==    at 0x43503B8: cvflann::KDTreeIndex<cvflann::L2<float> >::findNeighbors(cvflann::ResultSet<float>&, float const*, cvflann::SearchParams const&) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x43339E6: cvflann::NNIndex<cvflann::L2<float> >::knnSearch(cvflann::Matrix<float> const&, cvflann::Matrix<int>&, cvflann::Matrix<float>&, int, cvflann::SearchParams const&) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x431D5C9: cvflann::Index<cvflann::L2<float> >::knnSearch(cvflann::Matrix<float> const&, cvflann::Matrix<int>&, cvflann::Matrix<float>&, int, cvflann::SearchParams const&) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x1: ???
==23559==  Address 0xbeb8774c is just below the stack ptr.  To suppress, use: --workaround-gcc296-bugs=yes
==23559== 
==23559== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23559==    at 0x402A92A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==23559==    by 0x5502245: cv::SURF::~SURF() (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x56374D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==23559==  Address 0xbeb88060 is on thread 1's stack
==23559== 
==23559== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23559==    at 0x402A92A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==23559==    by 0x804B56F: cv::FlannBasedMatcher::~FlannBasedMatcher() (features2d.hpp:1120)
==23559==    by 0x56374D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==23559==  Address 0xbeb87e2c is on thread 1's stack
==23559== 
==23559== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==23559==    at 0x402A92A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==23559==    by 0x42AC883: cv::DescriptorMatcher::DescriptorCollection::~DescriptorCollection() (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x56374D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==23559==  Address 0x8eb0bd0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==23559==    at 0x402A92A: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==23559==    by 0x42AC883: cv::DescriptorMatcher::DescriptorCollection::~DescriptorCollection() (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.2)
==23559==    by 0x56374D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==23559==
```

3.Note: The first error belongs to the next declaration (again a pointer), which the error output classifies as an "uninitialised value created by a stack allocation". Is that true? If so, how can I fix it?

> CvFileStorage* storage = cvOpenFileStorage( "svm1.yml", 0,
> CV_STORAGE_READ );

---

### Question:

Is there some function or trick that I need to use in order to free the memory of the pointers or of any other element before the program tries to do it and fails?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cv::Ptr` is for dynamically allocated objects.  `extractor1`, and `matcher1` aren't dynamically allocated.  They will be freed automatically when they go out of scope.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vaughn, that was exactly what I needed to know :) Right declaration: `Ptr<DescriptorMatcher > matcher = new FlannBasedMatcher;
     Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor(new SurfDescriptorExtractor());`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the legacy API

```
CvFileStorage* storage = cvOpenFileStorage( "svm1.yml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
```

use the OpenCV 2 API

```
cv::FileStorage storage("svm1.yml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
```

then you don't need to worry about pointers.

See [the OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)

Comment: Thanks for your advice @user2151446, but the problem here is that the function: `virtual void read( CvFileStorage* storage, CvFileNode* node );` needs a pointer. I wish I could use it without a pointer, because Valgrind is still notifying me an `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation`, but anyway the problem during the normal execution has dissapeared, so for the time being I guess I can live without worrying about it.